# How do I get audited in India and what happens after that?

Tags: taxes, india, audit

I have not filed my tax returns for 5 years. However I have a few FD's in my name and I was wondering what would happen if I were to get audited and how do these  audits take place. In the bank they ask for PAN number every time you deposit more than Rs. 50,000 and I have given out my PAN number quite a few times. I have also heard that they probably seize bank accounts. Can somebody please explain the process to me?

Answer (score 3):

Not filing a Return in itself is not a crime. If your income is less than the prescribed threshold or you belong to certain categories you need not file a tax return.

If you are a taxpayer in most cases you must file a return. If you fall under certain categories [for example own a house or have travelled abroad etc] you must file NIL return even if there is no tax due.

The audit are done by Income Tax officials. If your accounts get audited and there is a tax due, you would get a demand request for last 5 years along with penalties and interest that are substantially high. Plus there could be other charges as well.

Its best to consult a CA to advice as to how late returns can be filed and best course of action.